# Chart.js not working - Uncaught RefernceError:

Tags: javascript, php, html, chart.js, psql

I am trying to display in chart form some data on time series data using chart.js. The data is fetched from psql, converted to json, and sent as an argument to js function to render a chart.

The data is received properly in js but there are errors 'Uncaught RefernceError' about the js function call in HTML.

**EDIT**

It's raising these errors:

```
Uncaught RefernceError: dspChrt is not defined @ line
 dspChrt(WData);
    </script>          
        </body>
    </html>
```

Here is my code:

**JS**

```
<script>
    var Device_Data;
    var rssi, batt;
    var rssiArray = [];
    var battArray = [];
    var N = 12;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        rssiArray.push(0);
        battArray.push(0); }

function dspChrt(Device_Data) { 

    console.log(Device_Data[0].rssi);
    console.log(Device_Data[1].battery_voltage_mv);
    rssi = Device_Data[0].rssi;
    batt = Device_Data[1].battery_voltage_mv;
    rssiArray.shift();
    rssiArray.push(rssi);
    battArray.shift();
    battArray.push(batt);

    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
    labels: [new Date()],
    datasets: [{
    label: 'rssi',
    data: rssiArray, 
    backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.4)"
        }, {
    label: 'Battery_Voltage',
    data: battArray,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.4)"
    }]
    }
    options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            time: {
                unit: 'hour',
            }
        }]
    }
}


}); 
}

 //var myVar = setInterval(dspChrt, 60000);
</script>
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
 <?php
    require("Connection.php");
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("Select date_time, battery_voltage_mv FROM measuring_device_statuses LIMIT 24");
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $WData = $stmt->fetchAll();

    /*
    echo "<pre>".print_r($WData, true)."</pre>"; 
    die();
    */

    ?>

    <script>
      var WData = <?php print_r(json_encode($WData));?>;
      //console.log(WData);
      dspChrt(WData);
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I looked at your code, I found `labels` were configured, however your timestamp format will never match those labels. As a result, showing 0 makes sense.

Not sure what do you want. Maybe something like [this](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/time/line-point-data.html)?
Take a look at the script they coded, you will find out they didn't configure `labels`.

If I were you, I might use scatter plot with `showLines=true` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much chouhy !
Yes, something like that in the link I want. The time I want to appear in label horizontal & other parameters over time then in the graph.
If the code for the link available, will help a lot. Can you please help edit my code for time to appear in label like in the link. I have basically 15 minutes interval.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+i and you can find the script of that link in <body>.

Comment: I edited the code but it's still complaining about syntax where I put 'options'.